# String Search in ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I am using Netezza.

One of my columns (COMMENTS) in my table (TABLE1) has text.
COMMENTS column is a free text column and can have any text in it.
Here are a few samples of how the text looks:

```
OLD STUDENT:N(Y/N/U=UNKNOWN) Some other text could be here
Some other text could be here  OLD STUDENT:Y(Y/N/U=UNKNOWN)
OLD STUDENT:Y(Y/N/U=UNKNOWN) Some other text could be here
```

**Note**: Some records have "" between OLD STUDENT: and Y

I want to filter records based on text search.
The idea is to isolate records having the text "STUDENT:Y"

Here is what I have so far but is not working:

```
SELECT COMMENTS
FROM
 TABLE1
WHERE
 LOWER(COMMENTS) LIKE '%student%'   
 AND LOWER(COMMENTS) NOT LIKE '%student:n%'
```

How do I handle this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't understand your `WHERE` logic.  Are you trying to find records which _do_ have `STUDENT:Y`, or records which _don't_ have it?  Your current query seems to be doing the latter.

Comment: Sorry Tim, should have been student:n. Corrected.

Comment: What would be wrong with `WHERE LOWER(COMMENTS) LIKE '%student:y%' ?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Tim, Even though there are valid records, WHERE LOWER(COMMENTS) LIKE '%student:y% is not returning any results, no idea why. some of the text fields have weird characters between the student: and y. StackOverflow editor does not seem to be recognizing them. Wondering if they could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for making me think this through. Adding another wild card between student: and y like this, WHERE LOWER(COMMENTS) LIKE '%student:_y% did the trick.

Comment: Figure out what your actual data is, and then write a query which targets that actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are valid records, WHERE LOWER(COMMENTS) LIKE '%student:y% where not returning any results. Some of the text fields have weird characters between the **student:** and **y**

Adding another single wildcard character "_" solved the issue.

```
SELECT COMMENTS
FROM
 TABLE1
WHERE
 LOWER(COMMENTS) LIKE '%student%'   
 AND LOWER(COMMENTS) NOT LIKE '%student:_n%'
```